# Trouble with Linked Lists and pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, linked-list

I'm having some trouble understanding exactly what I'm doing wrong here.

I have a program, written in C, which adds elements to a queue from multiple threads. From my debugging, I can see that the mutex locks are working as intended, but every time the worker thread adds an element to the linked list, it is lost by the time the next thread comes around.

For Example, if thread 1 comes in first, the queue will have element 1 in slot 0.
Next, thread 2 comes in and appends itself, which works correctly (printing out the contents of the array before the method returns back will have both threads 1 and 2 in the queue). However, the next time a thread calls pushToQueue, the queue will only have one element (the original element) inside, and it will append itself to what it believes is the only element in the array

Here is my simplified code, the function schedule() is called by a thread in another class:

```
//Global Variables
struct node* readyQueue = NULL;
pthread_mutex_t readyLock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t computeReadyCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;


void pushToQueue(struct node* inthread) {
    struct node* cur = inthread;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&readyLock);
    if (findInReadyQueue(cur->tid) != NULL) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&readyLock);
        return;
    }
    if (readyQueue == NULL) {
        // No list exists, so we must create it.
        readyQueue = cur;
        readyQueue->next = NULL;
        readyQueue->prev = NULL;
    }
    else {
        // append the current thread to the end
        struct node* tmp = readyQueue;
        struct node* prev = NULL;
        while (tmp != NULL) {
            prev = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        prev->next = cur;
        cur->next = NULL;
    }
    pthread_cond_signal(&computeReadyCond); //Signal other threads that the queue is ready
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&readyLock);
}

//Calling method (called from a pthread in another class)
int schedule(float currentTime, int tid, int remainingTime, int tprio) {
    // update global time
    global_currentTime = currentTime;

    // create a new structure for this thread to put in the queue
    struct node curThread;
    curThread.tid = tid;
    curThread.remainingTime = remainingTime;
    curThread.tprio = tprio;
    curThread.calledAt = currentTime;
    curThread.state = NEW;

    if (curThread.remainingTime <= 0) {
        removeFromQueue(tid);
        return global_currentTime;
    }

    // push the thread to its queue based on scheduler rules
    pushToQueue(&curThread);
    waitForCompute(tid);
    printf("wait thread has joined from thread %d\n", tid);
    return global_currentTime;
}

void waitForCompute(int input) {
    int tid = input;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&readyLock);
    while (readyQueue->tid != tid) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&computeReadyCond, &readyLock);
    }
pthread_mutex_unlock(&readyLock);
}
```

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: At least in this code snippet  prev->next = cur;
        cur->next = NULL; there is a bug. You forgot to set the data member prev of the node pointed to by the pointer cur: cur->prev = prev;

Comment: Why do you add a copy for the parameter you receive in `pushToQueue()`? In any case, you should have extracted a [mcve] first and included that in your question, which is off-topic without it. As a new user, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I don't see anything in the code presented that would explain the behavior described,  though do be mindful of the possible issue raised in @blacix's answer.  I'm inclined to think that some code not shown is responsible the unexpected node removals, directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the address of a local variable to `pushToQueue` from `schedule`, which you never should.

```
int schedule(float currentTime, int tid, int remainingTime, int tprio) {
    // ...
    // create a new structure for this thread to put in the queue
    struct node curThread;
    // ...
    pushToQueue(&curThread);
```

When `schedule` returns, that memory area is deallocated. You set the global variable `struct node* readyQueue` to this memory address in `pushToQueue` method, and add items to readyQueue, but a `redyQueue` points to variable on the stack, which is discarded when the function returns.
It can happen that always the same memory address is used for `struct node curThread;` in `schedule` method, so `readyQueue` always points to a node struct, which is being recreated each time schedule is called.

Comment: Although the issue you describe could cause the OP's linked list to contain invalid links, there's no reason to think that it would cause the list to appear to be valid, but with fewer elements than expected, as the OP describes.  I am inclined to guess that you have been fooled by omissions from the OP's code: my expectation would be that their `waitForCompute()` function does not return while the object in question remains enqueued, so that the particular problem described in this answer does not arise.